# Why the sshd service is unrecognized?

Tags: hadoop, ssh, sshd

I'm trying to install hadoop, and I need to restart the sshd service in order to configure the connection between the nodes... However, whenever I write: `service sshd restart` a message error will be displayed telling me that this service is not recognized.

Any help to install this system?

Comment: Seeing the same problem with Trusty Tahr.

Answer (score 21):

In Ubuntu, install sshd client and server with these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Then, to restart sshd, type:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

This worked for me, when I had the same problem. You can find more information [here](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-openssh).

Comment: yes, but wait should I reboot the node or restart it?

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu? What happens when you type: `which sshd`? If nothing is output, it means that sshd is not installed. I don't think that you need to reboot.

Comment: No, it didn't work :(
and when I write "which sshd", I get /usr/sbin/sshd

Comment: Then, it is not an installation problem. Based on your distribution, check this site and this, I am afraid, is my last guess (put sudo in the front): http://www.starnet.com/xwin32kb/restart_sshd

Comment: Now I'm having another problem, if fact I cannot anymore add ssh keys
whenever I write ssh-add key.pem it tells me 
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
I cannot understand, is it because of these command that you have given to me?

Answer (score 4):

Try these commands:

For Debian/Ubuntu

```
/etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

For RedHat and Fedora Core Linux

```
/sbin/service sshd restart
```

Comment: For Debian/Ubuntu try **/etc/init.d/ssh restart**